# what is way to use `.env` file in gitlab continues integration

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab

my docker-compose file  like this

```
services:
  database:
    container_name: postgres
    hostname: db
    image: postgres:12-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=Database_User
   ports:
      - "54321:5432"
   env_file:
      - .env
```

and when I run `CI` on gitlab. As I can't put my .env file on gitlab its giving error    **Couldn't find env file:**

So what is way to use `.env` file in gitlab-CI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unstead of `env_file` you can add variable under "settings/ci_cd"

[image]

Here an exemple of "docker-compose.yml"

```yaml
version: '3.3'
services:
  var:
    image: alpine:latest
    command: echo $TEST_VAR
```

and here my .gitlab-ci.yml

```yaml
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: docker/compose
  script:
    - export TEST_VAR=$test_var
    - docker-compose up
```

and here the resulte in the ci:

[image]

So just copy all your vars from your .env file into /settins/ci_cd and add export them in `script:` before `docker-compose up`.

You can read more about variable in CI [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/).

Comment: thanks for reply . actually I have 10 variables in .env file . how I will assign here ? not getting your point

Comment: And 2nd point is its must that I will use  env file in production .

Comment: So create 10 variables in CI... And if you really want an env file, instead of export them echo them to the env file `echo $VAR >> .env` before the `docker-compose up`

Comment: so you are saying  if  I have 10 vars named    var1 , var2 ... var10  . I will do    echo $VAR1 >> .env
$VAR2 >> .env
$VAR3 >> .env
`before docker up` ?

Comment: no i forget one thing, it sould be `- echo "VAR1=$var1" >> .env` then go in new line and  `- echo "VAR2=$var2" >> .env` etc ...

Comment: I added   `TEST_VAR` in  gitlab CI  variables and tried to get in gitlab-ci file like this 

`- echo "VAR1=$TEST_VAR" >> .env`  but I am getting  ' '  instead . not value